# How to identify an input box in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium

I am using Selenium Webdriver for the first time and am running a very simple script, but it is not working.  I would like to open Firefox, go to LinkedIn, and enter my email address in the email login field.  Using the code below, I'm able to get the first two operations to work, but the script is not properly identifying the email field, and so my email address is never being typed in anywhere.

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()   #Get local session of firefox
browser.get("http://www.linkedin.com")  #Load page
elem = browser.find_element_by_name("session_key-login")  #Find the login box
elem.send_keys("email@gmail.com" + Keys.RETURN)   #Enter email into login box
```

How do I correctly identify the email login box and pass it to "elem"?

Answer (score 0):

How about you just do

```
elem.send_keys("email@gmail.com")
```

UPDATE

---

The identifier used by you was incorrect, you can use either one of the below.

`elem = browser.find_element_by_id("session_key-login")`

`elem = browser.find_element_by_name("session_key")`

Comment: Just tried it but it didn't work.  I think the issue is the "session_key-login" is not the right way to identify the email input box, but I'm not sure how else to name it, I saw that identifier when I inspected the element on Firefox.

Comment: try giving
        elem = browser.find_element_by_id("session_key-login")
instead of
        elem = browser.find_element_by_name("session_key-login")

Comment: Awesome, thanks, that worked perfectly.  Strangely, the find_element_by_name function worked well to find input fields in the main body of the page (ie. "firstName" found the first name input box), but not for input fields in the header.  In any case, I'll use the id instead!

Comment: @Misha, just checked Linkedin.com and the `id=session_key-login` and the `name=session_key`. I have updated the answer as well. If you think the answer has helped you please mark the answer correct. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Answer (score 0):

Try giving
element.send_keys("email@gmail.com");

instead of

```
    elem.send_keys("email@gmail.com" + Keys.RETURN)
```